# how i can manually login to HG router using curl?

Tags: html, authentication, curl, cookies, cgi

the problem that i tried the curl command from chrome network tab and it didn't work !
so i looked in [the page html](https://www.pastiebin.com/5d1b8c66753f7) and found that it does this

1- Encrypt the password to sha256

2- then base64 encode the sha256 hash

3- then add the hash to the challange ( that it gets from another page )

4- then sha 256 the output

i tried to that step by step and it still doesn't work !
the curl command from chrome without cleaning

```
curl "http://192.168.1.1/index/login.cgi" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/html/index.asp" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8" -H "Cookie: Language=en; SessionID_R3=7EGmyRl6PcjZyCodTPl8zshYtbagRfUEIYm4njyVzkHAjoRgfeg8OLYerWewZlUwo5r4FeTPnsbRyB7eeCiVNf22aoU6E7eDAqAXc4w8iINkdt3srn3pdKYCDjvXmZw5; FirstMenu=Admin_0; SecondMenu=Admin_0_0; ThirdMenu=Admin_0_0_0" --data "Username=admin&Password=3bacd54fb595f90906feb6c68659c96bee5a2f4a594aea3fc50a56c306a04cb5&challange=IkYo7bcXU68FzOOzCPBg" --compressed --insecure
```

the command after cleaning it up a little bit

```
curl "http://192.168.1.1/index/login.cgi" -H "Cookie: Language=en; FirstMenu=Admin_0; SecondMenu=Admin_0_0; ThirdMenu=Admin_0_0_0"   --data "Username=user&Password=16e1c03a0075fa68ddca3398b5cd6342692cb9868b68a4c9c0a92b89311667a8&challange=KCoMUJ4u3SEf7bfDJ3o9"
```

i have removed SessionID_R3 from it as i think it's not necessary and tried the command with it and it didn't make any difference.
a succeed connection in wireshark
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCZ6r.png)

[and the chrome network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8eaF.png)

Comment: record a login with Fiddler Proxy and post the Fiddler log

Comment: @hanshenrik fiddler doesn't work with me i don't know why !!
"i see no attempt to hash the password at all"
sorry it seems that i made a mistake here is [the one that i am talking about](https://www.pastiebin.com/5d1b8c66753f7)
at the lines 130-132 exactly 
`var dbpass = base64encode(SHA256(Password.value));
var realpass = dbpass + challange;
form.addParameter('Password', SHA256(realpass));`
and btw 
i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: fncKeyStop is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeydown ((index):279)"
and

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: base64encode is not defined
    at SubmitForm ((index):129)
    at XMLHttpRequest.SubmitFormWithChallange.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  

....... when i don't use incognito window..
here is a the params from network tab `Username=user&Password=b6e01236291bd3b95e9944ef3209f5be186dfdc473e2a91ae3f1f49e62983078&challange=pH7FP1cU2CUd9kXpmMuq`
the password is user try it yourself .
"because they don't know about the encodeURIComponent javascript function"
i don't how this real cause they use the same thing even in newer versions !!

Comment: @hanshenrik i fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the SessionID_R3 isn't necessary to login but necessary to view auth required pages and it gives you a new one when you successful login

the working command

```
curl "http://192.168.1.1/index/login.cgi" -H "Cookie: Language=en" --data "Username=user&Password=16e1c03a0075fa68ddca3398b5cd6342692cb9868b68a4c9c0a92b89311667a8&challange=KCoMUJ4u3SEf7bfDJ3o9"
```

i would have removed the cookies from it but it's required .

the problem was additional space in the forth step that resulted in a wrong hashed 'password+challange'